How to enter a Hatch shell development environment in the VS Code debugger launch profile when debugging django
I'm trying to launch my Django application using VS codes debugger. I need to run the command 'hatch shell' to enter my hatch development environment before running the server command 'py manage.py runserver'. I can't find out how to do this using the VS code debugger profile specified in the launch.json file below.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Django",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/testproject/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}

I tried to run 'hatch shell' as a preLaunchTask but that runserver command did not run in the shell environment.
Helpful resources:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-debugger-launch-profile
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

The VS Code debugger doesn't support running commands in a shell before launching the debugger.

In Hatch projects I use VSCODE launch configurations property envFile
...
"envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
...

Then in the .env file add:
PATH="<HATCH ENV PATH>:${PATH}"

Use the following command to find the path:
hatch env find hatch-test

